# Terminating a pointer to a pointer?

Tags: c

I get no compiler warning from this but it segfaults. So how can I copy a '\0' at the beginning of the string so I can then use strncat ? (The use of strncpy is not allowed and using memcpy and then terminating the string segfaults also.)

I wrote this to illustrate the problem:

```
void func(char **str)
{
    *str = realloc(*str, -);
    *str[0] = '\0'; // I get segfault here.
    strncat(*str, -, -);

    // memcpy(*str, -, -);
    // *str[strlen(*str)] = '\0'; // I get segfault here.
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = NULL;
    func(&str);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: I meant to write strlen(*str) and not strlen(str). Sorry.

Comment: This is a `C` question, not a `C++` question.

Comment: realloc(*str, -); doesn't look particularly legal - is there a typo?

Comment: I think the OP has probably just omitted irrelevant arguments - look at the strncat and memcpy calls as well.

Comment: I would argue that they're very much not irrelevant, specifically you can fill in those arguments and get a program that works.

Comment: Yes, I wrote dashes because that information is irrelevant and would clutter the example.

Comment: Since you're clearly a neophyte C programmer, you don't have good judgment as to what is or is not irrelevant. Post the code you ran.

Comment: @Jim: I'd go further - whether you're neophyte or not if you don't know what's wrong with your code then you don't have good judgement what's relevant. Reducing to a minimal test case demonstrating the problem *solves* the problem half the time, it's just like explaining your problem to a stuffed toy.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the second segfaulting line is operator precedence.

`[]` has higher precedence than `*`, so `*str[strlen(*str)]` is interpreted as `*(str[strlen(*str)])` - that is, dereference the address pointed to by the memory at `str + strlen(*str)`.

You want `(*str)[strlen(*str)]` - that is, the character at the end of of `str`-dereferenced.

Comment: Jeez, don't be so wishy-washy. The problem *is* operator precedence and the OP *does* want `(*str)[0]` -- or `**str`.

Comment: You are correct, although for `*str[0]` it is pretty much irrelevant since `*str[0]` is defined as `**(str+0) == **str` which is the same as `(*str)[0] == *((*str)+0) == **str`. But the `*str[strlen(str)]` is bound to segfault.

Comment: I'm pretty sure **str str[0][0] *str[0] and (*str)[0] would all evaluate to the same thing - the first character of the string.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was hesitating. And in fact [codepad agrees](http://codepad.org/IT9Nv9es) - the first indicated line does not fail.

Comment: But ... if you have doubts about your answer, you should check it before posting, not engage in all that wishy-washy talk. Since you now know that your answer is wrong, you should do the right thing and withdraw it.

Comment: You're right, I should have checked. However, since my answer is correct for the second segfault (and the first suspect line of code is fine if the realloc succeeds), I shall simply edit my answer to reflect what it applies to.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation faults occur when the memory being accessed by the program is invalid. It is very likely that the realloc call was not able to allocate the amount of memory being requested. It is a best practice to check whether the memory is properly allocated before proceeding to access it.

I tried this program and works well in my system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    void func(char **str)
    {
        *str = realloc(*str, sizeof(char) * 20);
        if( *str == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
            return;
        }

        *str[0] = '\0';
        strncat(*str, "hello world", 11);  
        //memcpy(*str, "hello world", 11); //memcpy also works fine
        //(*str) [strlen(*str)] = '\0';   
        printf("String : %s\n", *str);
     }
```